# Как искать похожие изображения между двумя папками?

Tags: linux, изображения

Есть ли возможность у `findimagedupes` сравнивать изображения в одной папке с другой?

Например, в одной папке 100 изображений, и в другой столько же. В первой папке есть одно изображение, более, чем на 85%, похожее на одно изображение в другой папке.

Я пробовал делать так:

```
findimagedupes -t 85 "первая_папка/*"  "вторая_папка/*"
```

но дело в том, что он показывает совпадения, которые нашлись в первой папке и/или во второй. А надо, чтобы сообщал, что «найдено изображение в папке *первая_папка*, которое совпадает с изображением во *вторая_папка*»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно в цикле перебрать все пары файлов:

```sh
$ for f1 in первый_каталог/*; do \
   for f2 in второй_каталог/*; do \
    findimagedupes -t 85 $f1 $f2; done; done
```

---

если же требуется, чтобы в выводимых строках пары файлов не были перемешаны (первым может идти файл то из первого, то из второго каталога), то можно каждую строку отсортировать, воспользовавшись возможностью программы `findimagedupes` передавать получаемые строки на обработку указанному скрипту (см. [`man findimagedupes`](http://www.jhnc.org/findimagedupes/manpage.html)):

```sh
$ for f1 in первый_каталог/*; do \
   for f2 in второй_каталог/*; do \
    findimagedupes -t 85 -i \
    'VIEW(){ for f in "$@"; do echo $f; done | sort | xargs echo; }' -- \
    $f1 $f2; done; done
```

---

такой перебор каждого-с-каждым довольно ресурсоёмок («отпечатки»-*fingerprints* вычисляются при каждом запуске), поэтому для большей оптимальности следует либо дополнить нужной функциональностью саму программу, либо, вызывая её для всех файлов сразу, несколько усложнить скрипт, передаваемый программе опцией `-i`.

---

**обновление**

«усложнил» скрипт:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

d1=$(realpath $1)
d2=$(realpath $2)

e1=$(echo $d1 | sed 's,/,\\/,g')

findimagedupes -t 85 -i 'VIEW() { n1=$(for f in "$@"; do echo $f; done \
 | sed -n "/^'$e1'/{p;q}"); n2=$(for f in "$@"; do echo $f; done \
 | grep "^'$d2'" | xargs echo); if [ -n "$n1" -a "$n2" ]; then \
 for f in "$@"; do echo $f; done | sed -n "/^'$e1'/!{s|^|$n1 |;p}"; fi; \
}' $d1/* $d2/*
```

вызывается он с двумя параметрами: `первый_каталог` `второй_каталог` (без каких-либо масок, просто пути к каталогам). для каждой строки, генерируемой программой, он оставляет только один файл из первого каталога (первый встретившийся), но разбивает её на несколько строк так, чтобы в каждой получившейся строке было только по одному файлу из второго каталога.

например, строку `dir1/file1 dir1/file2 dir2/file1 dir2/file2` он заменит на две строки:

```
dir1/file1 dir2/file1
dir1/file1 dir2/file2
```

и, конечно, строки, в которых присутствуют только файлы из первого или только из второго каталога, игнорируются.